# robocopy to preserve some extra files

Tags: robocopy

I have a problem with robocopy and with extra files in particular.

I would like to run robocopy to keep two directories almost in "sync" and thus it would be natural to use the /MIR option along with /MON:x to keep the process alive.

I need to copy a list of files, let's assume for example *.tif, from SRC to DST and it is ok when robocopy is removing from DST extra files that matches the file pattern.

But with the /MIR option, robocopy is removing all extra files even if they are not matching the *.tif

I tried to use the /XX option, but this is actually preserving all extra files. I believed I could add a path or filename to the /XX but it is not accepted.

I tried to use the /XF *.png option in order to exclude the png files, but this is only applied on the SRC and not on the DST.

Does a solution to this problem exist?

Thanks in advance for your help,